# Trying to Vectorise the following for time efficiency MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to optimize the time efficiency of the following MATLAB code, it currently takes in excess of 4 hours to run (I have preallocated the two structures just not included that part here):

```
for combination = 1:1771

  for hankel_size = 1:4;

    for window = 1:999

      Output.bin_r(:, window, combination, hankel_size) = bsxfun(@minus, data.hankel_index_mean(window, combination ,hankel_size),centers(window, :, hankel)');
      Output.score(window, combination, hankel_size) = probs(window, :, hankel_size)*Output.bin_r(:, window, combination, hankel_size);

    end

  end

end
```

Note that:

- centers is a 999 x 50 x 4 matrix
- hankel_index_mean is a 999 x 1771 x 4 matrix
- probs is a 999 x 50 x 4 matrix

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Short answer: Get rid of structures.

Comment: By structures are you referencing 'Output'?

Comment: I would start off with creating a regular array version of `Output.bin_r`.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow when you say a 'regular array', simply a 1D array?

Comment: It looks like your forloops are independent: try and use <code>parfor</code> for one of the forloops. (Not all three, nested parfors do not work)

Comment: @Devesh That would be a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @A.Visser, you're right! Exploring that at the moment. It has dramatically reduced the required time.

Comment: @Devesh in that case I'll make an answer out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parfor combination = 1:1771

  for hankel_size = 1:4;

    for window = 1:999

      Output.bin_r(:, window, combination, hankel_size) = bsxfun(@minus, data.hankel_index_mean(window, combination ,hankel_size),centers(window, :, hankel)');
      Output.score(window, combination, hankel_size) = probs(window, :, hankel_size)*Output.bin_r(:, window, combination, hankel_size);

    end

  end

end
```

`parfor` utilises all the cores in your CPU.

Open a parallel pool by either the matlab default which opens one on the calling of parallel functions (eg `parfor` or `spmd`) or open one explicitly by calling `parpool` or `gcp`.

Edit parallel preferences under Home->parallel->parallel preferences.